# Form POST request not captured by Laravel 7 route

Tags: laravel, post

I have a form that sends back data with a POST to Laravel. The issue is that the POST is not captured by the route that I created. I get a 404.

**The form**

```
        <form  action="/articles" method="post">

        <div class='field'>
            <label class='label' for='title'>Title</label>

            <div class='control'>
                <input class='input' type='text' name='title' id='title'>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='field'>
            <label class='label' for='excerpt'>Excerpt</label>

            <div class='control'>
                <textarea class='textarea' name='excerpt'  id='excerpt'></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='field'>
            <label class='label' for='body'>Body</label>

            <div class='control'>
                <textarea class="textarea" name='body' id='body'></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='field is-grouped'>
            <div class='control'>
                <button class='button is-link' type='submit'>Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

My route file:

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Route::get('/articles', 'ArticlesController@index');
Route::post('/articles', 'ArticlesController@store');
Route::get('/articles/create', 'ArticlesController@create');
```

I have tried all kinds of variations in the action and the method, but I always get a 404.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You say you've tried all kinds of variations, but what, specifically have you tried? Did you try with the `url()` helper? `action="{{ url('/articles') }}"`? Did you try with a named route? `Route::post('/articles', ...)->name('articles');` and `action="{{ route('articles') }}"`? Also, one note, you need a CSRF token inside your `<form>` for a `POST` method: `{{ csrf_field() }}`

Comment: I tried longer URL's like "/public/articles", I replaced POST by GET. But your advise to use the URL helper function solved the problem. Thanx for that. Do you have any idea why "/articles" did not work? I literally copied it from the "Laravel from scratch" videos from laracast.com.

Comment: Yup! Posting a quick answer for ya, 1 sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `action="/articles"`, you wind up with what is known as a "relative path", i.e. it tries to append `/articles` to whatever your current URL is. Looking at your Routes, this means it's trying to `POST` to

> `http://localhost:8000/articles/create/articles`

The `url()` helper creates an "absolute path", which has no ambiguity, and results in the correct URL:

> `http://localhost:8000/articles`

Note: Your URL might be a different host, but the logic still applies.

Comment: Tim, Thx for the reply. I already suspected that it has something to do with the "current folder". But what I am still not getting is how the path is determined that is put before the "articles"? Is it the location of the php file in which the form is defined? Or is it the root of the Laravel project? Or another way?

Comment: It's your current URL. If you're submitting the form from `http://localhost/articles/create`, with the action `/articles`, the fully qualified URL it'll be posting to is `http://localhost/articles/create/articles`. That's why you need the absolute URL generated by the `url()` helper. Nothing to do with folder in this case :) Path is referring to URL path, not folder path.

Comment: Cklear now. Thanx.  Hubert